# New Rails app drawing some data from legacy tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, legacy-database

I have a new rails app which needs to access data from a legacy table called "Doo_dad", with an autoincrementing primary key called "id", and a string field called "name".

So I created a new model file called **app/models/doodad.rb** which looks like this:

```
class Doodad < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name "Doo_dad"
end
```

When I loaded Rails console, I could reach my Rails-generated models, but I could not see the class

```
> rails console
irb> Doodad.class
NameError: uninitialized constant Doodad
(from (irb):1: in `evaluate`
```

Class Doodad in **app/models/doodad.rb** was not getting loaded. This code is good, because when I did the following:

```
> rails console
irb> class Doodad < ActiveRecord::Base
irb> set_table_name "Doo_dad"
irb> end
irb> Doodad.class
 => OK
irb> d=Doodad.new
irb> d.name="Uno"
irb> d.save
 => OK no errors
```

i.e. When I monkey-patched in the contents of **app/models/doodad.rb**, everything was fine, and the Doodad called "Uno" was saved into the database.

How can I get Rails to load up my model classes which hook up to legacy tables?

Comment: What errors? Stuff like "what happens" is often a useful diagnostic tool.

Comment: Does the table show up in `schema.rb`?

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant Doodad

Comment: The schema isn't in schema.rb, but I wouldn't expect it to  because I didn't create a migration for it. And schema.rb doesn't contain any of the symbols defined in any of the model classes as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! I had the class in **app/models/doodads.rb**. Once I renamed it to **app/models/doodad.rb**,  everything was fine.

I guess that the convention of one model class per file with the Rails model file naming convention (filename=classname.underscore+".rb") is an absolute "must" to get this working.